# Show $f(x,y) = (x^2+y^2)\sin(1/\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ is differentiable at the origin

Tags: linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

With
$f(x,y) = \\(x^2+y^2)\sin(1/\sqrt{x^2+y^2} : (x,y) \neq 0, \\0 : (x,y) = 0$

Using the definition of differentiability, would I expand $f(v + h)$ (the vector representation) to f(x+h,y+h), then go from there, and deduce the linear transform needed to set the limit to $0$? I'm not sure how to proceed in that case, because I don't know how to manipulate the equation to isolate $h$ or however to make the problem manageable.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Note that
$$\dfrac{|f(x,y)-f(0)|}{\|(x,y)\|}\le \dfrac{x^2+y^2}{\|(x,y)\|}=\|(x,y)\|\to0$$ when $(x,y)\to0$.
Hence, the derivative exists and is the vector $(0,0)$, since the only linear transformation $L(x,y)=(ax,by)$ such that $$\dfrac{|f(x,y)-f(0)-L(x,y)|}{\|(x,y)\|}\to0$$ when $(x,y)\to0$, is obtained taking $a=b=0$.

Answer (score 1):

Another method, $x:=r\cos{\theta}, y:=r\sin{\theta}, r\geq 0, \theta{ \in \mathbb{R}}$.

$f(x,y)=r^2\sin{\frac{1}{r}} \Rightarrow \frac{|f(x,y)-f(0,0)|}{||(x,y)||}=|r\sin{\frac{1}{r}}|\leq |r| \rightarrow 0$